# Highlight favourited tags on mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, tag-watching

The great thing about favourited tags is being able to quickly parse the front and main pages for questions that you might be able to answer.  So why can't we have this on the mobile app?

Comment: iOS or android?

Comment: I'm on android, but does it really matter?

Comment: Yes it matters very much for proper tagging. [meta-tag:mobile] tag is for question about the mobile theme of the site, not about the app and there are two apps.